# mongodb using $exist in aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Isit possible to use $exist with aggregation as I want to get the specific projection too.. Something like that:

```
db.customerOrder.aggregate([
    {
        "phone":{"$exists":false}
    },
    {
        "$project":{"firstName":1, "lastName":1, "_id":0}
    }
])
```

I want to find the firstName and lastName of a customer who doesnt have a phone.

Comment: what you want to archive

Comment: @Ifaruki i want to get the firstName and lastName of the customers who doesnt have a phone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to use aggregation just to get a projection, you can do that with find:

```
db.customerOrder.find({phone: {$exists: false}}, {"firstName": 1, "lastName": 1, "_id": 0})
```

You should note that if a document has `phone` explicitly set to `null` it will not be matched by `{$exists:false}`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
db.customerOrder.aggregate([
{
    $match:{"phone":{"$exists":false}}
},
{
    "$project":{"firstName":1, "lastName":1, "_id":0}
}
])
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26233827)

Comment: @zonksoft I think the answer does answer the question, although some more explanation is encouraged